# Output data from today's date to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using php to encode MySQL data to JSON,below is my JSON data

```
{
"data": [
[
1427612400000,
"20"
],
[
1427526000000,
"22"
],
[
1427439600000,
"26"
]]
}
```

How do i output a single value from today's date (example: like below)

```
{
"data": 
[["20"]]
}
```

PHP Code:
In this code Date is "1427612400000" and 11_OIC is "20" from the above json data.
I would like to fetch just 11_OIC data from today's date.

```
private function productionhourlys(){   
            if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
                $this->response('',406);
            }
            $query="SELECT distinct  c.Date, c.11_OIC FROM productionhourlys c order by c.Date desc";
            $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    if($r->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $r->fetch_row()) {
        $row[0] = strtotime($row[0])*1000;
        $result[] = $row;
        }
        $pass = array(
            'data' => $result
        );

        $this->response($this->json($pass), 200); // send user details
            }
        $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where you want to fetch this value.

You could assign the JSON to a JavaScript variable and access it via JavaScript.

For example, in PHP echo the below tag so it shows up in the HTML:

```
<script type="javascript">foo = {"data": "20"}</script>
```

And you could access foo.data in a different javascript file.